# Unity: can't move when deploying Google Cardboard VR app as standalone/web?

Tags: web, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I have created a VR app in Unity with Google Cardboard SDK and am now attempting to deploy it to Web and as a standalone. The game works well on iPhone and Android and the user navigates the game by turning their head and touching the screen (the "Fire1" command I believe). The problem comes when I switch platforms.

In the editor when testing, even though my computer is not strapped to my head I have been able to still play the game just as well by holding down the Alt key to turn and just clicking the screen to move. I assumed this would be the same when deploying to a standalone but I'm having a problem:

When deploying to web and standalone, the user cannot move at all thus I'm not even sure if the game is working at all - Holding the alt key does nothing and clicking the screen does nothing. They cannot play the game.

What is wrong here? Are there other inputs that I can implement specifically for standalone to replace head tracking, etc? How are other Google Cardboard VR apps deployed to web?

In my WebplayerDevice script:

```
//For web support

#if UNITY_WEBPLAYER

using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CardboardWebplayerDevice : BaseCardboardDevice {

    // Simulated neck model.  Vector from the neck pivot point to the point between the eyes.
    private static readonly Vector3 neckOffset = new Vector3(0, 0.075f, 0.08f);

    // Use mouse to emulate head in the editor.
    private float mouseX = 0;
    private float mouseY = 0;
    private float mouseZ = 0;

    public override void Init() {
        Input.gyro.enabled = true;
        Debug.Log ("ITS WEB!!");

    }

    public override bool SupportsNativeDistortionCorrection(List<string> diagnostics) {
        return false;  // No need for diagnostic message.
    }

    public override bool SupportsNativeUILayer(List<string> diagnostics) {
        return false;  // No need for diagnostic message.
    }

    // Since we can check all these settings by asking Cardboard.SDK, no need
    // to keep a separate copy here.
    public override void SetUILayerEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetVRModeEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetDistortionCorrectionEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetStereoScreen(RenderTexture stereoScreen) {}
    public override void SetSettingsButtonEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetAlignmentMarkerEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetVRBackButtonEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetShowVrBackButtonOnlyInVR(bool only) {}
    public override void SetNeckModelScale(float scale) {}
    public override void SetAutoDriftCorrectionEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetElectronicDisplayStabilizationEnabled(bool enabled) {}
    public override void SetTapIsTrigger(bool enabled) {}

    private Quaternion initialRotation = Quaternion.identity;

    private bool remoteCommunicating = false;
    private bool RemoteCommunicating {
        get {
            if (!remoteCommunicating) {
remoteCommunicating = Vector3.Dot(Input.gyro.rotationRate, Input.gyro.rotationRate) > 0.05;
            }
            return remoteCommunicating;
        }
    }

    public override void UpdateState() {
        Quaternion rot;
        if (Cardboard.SDK.UseUnityRemoteInput && RemoteCommunicating) {
            var att = Input.gyro.attitude * initialRotation;
            att = new Quaternion(att.x, att.y, -att.z, -att.w);
            rot = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0) * att;
        } else {
            bool rolled = false;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt)) {
                mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 5;
                if (mouseX <= -180) {
                    mouseX += 360;
                } else if (mouseX > 180) {
                    mouseX -= 360;
                }
                mouseY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 2.4f;
                mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -85, 85);
            } else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl)) {
                rolled = true;
                mouseZ += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 5;
                mouseZ = Mathf.Clamp(mouseZ, -85, 85);
            }
            if (!rolled && Cardboard.SDK.autoUntiltHead) {
                // People don't usually leave their heads tilted to one side for long.
                mouseZ = Mathf.Lerp(mouseZ, 0, Time.deltaTime / (Time.deltaTime + 0.1f));
            }
            rot = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, mouseX, mouseZ);
        }
        var neck = (rot * neckOffset - neckOffset.y * Vector3.up) * Cardboard.SDK.NeckModelScale;
        headPose.Set(neck, rot);

        triggered = Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);
        tilted = Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape);
    }


    public override void PostRender() {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    public override void UpdateScreenData() {
        Profile = CardboardProfile.GetKnownProfile(Cardboard.SDK.ScreenSize, Cardboard.SDK.DeviceType);
        ComputeEyesFromProfile();
        profileChanged = true;
    }

    public override void Recenter() {
        mouseX = mouseZ = 0;  // Do not reset pitch, which is how it works on the phone.
        if (RemoteCommunicating) {
            //initialRotation = Quaternion.Inverse(Input.gyro.attitude);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Errors (even when I changed the Webplayer device class to BaseVRDevice this made no difference) :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compile errors you are seeing are because the variables you are referring to in the Cardboard.cs script (autoUntiltHead, Screen, Device, etc) are all in a #if UNITY_EDITOR section.  Change that to #if UNITY_EDITOR || UNITY_WEBPLAYER, or just remove the #if.  Then you'll be able to compile.

Answer (score 0):

The key combos are only available within the Unity3d editor.

The Cardboard Unity3d SDK supports different behaviours for different platforms by loading the relevant device script under VRDevices:

https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/blob/master/Cardboard/Scripts/VRDevices

You will see that the UnityEditorDevice.cs has the code for handling the ALT and CTRL keys.

For a web deployment, I suggest you create a new device and implement mouse movements (without a key) to look around. You can get the Cardboard SDK to load your device by editing BaseVRDevice.cs:

```
    public static BaseVRDevice GetDevice() {
        if (device == null) {
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
          device = new UnityEditorDevice();
    #elif ANDROID_DEVICE
          device = new CardboardAndroidDevice();
    #elif IPHONE_DEVICE
          device = new CardboardiOSDevice();
    // Support your device here:
    #elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER
          device = new CardboardWebplayerDevice();
    #else
          throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported device.");
    #endif
        }
        return device;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I have written the above into BaseVRDevice.cs and created a CardboardWebplayerDevice script. I'm relatively new to this however I basically copy and pasted the code from UnityEditorDevice.cs into my web player device script so that the user controls would be the same. My code from CardboardWebplayerDevice.cs is in my question above. When I try to build for web I'm getting a ton of errors (I included a screenshot). What should I be doing here?

Comment: You have to strip out only the movement code. If you don't mind an external link - I have done that as an alternative script: http://talesfromtherift.com/unity-vr-editor-mouse-look-script/

Comment: What do you mean strip out the movement code? Don't I need to include all other override methods also? Sorry, new at this - looking at the VRMouseLook.cs script now. What did you take from that script and place in CardboardWebplayerDevice? How much do I keep from UnityEditorDevice?

Comment: do you make CardboardWebplayerDevice a subclass of BaseVRDevice or BaseCardboardDevice?